# SQL Server: Updating rows with dependencies in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

There is the table `CSBaumkontakt` and in this table I've contact persons and companies. `CSBaumkontakt` is a tree structure like this:

```
[+] master company (Root)
  [+] company (Dad)
    [+] contact person
```

The company (`Dad`) of a contact person is connected with its `DadPubIndex` and the `RelPubIndex` from the company. And the application works only properly if the `Dad` and `Root` of the company are the same as the `Root` of the contact person. This means the `RootPubIndex` of the contact person must be the same like the `DadPubindex` and the `RootPubindex` of its company. But this is not always the case.

See picture below **before** the change:

contact person

```
[RelPubIndex] [9FC6CD387AE91B46A471E1B82963E36A]
[RooPubIndex] [F7BC36A0-AD4F-49D5-B4FC-AD529C7EA738]
[DadPubIndex] [2143640C-3ABF-440C-B094-2128F4495874]
[class] [contact person]
```

company of the contact person

```
[RelPubIndex] [2143640C-3ABF-440C-B094-2128F4495874]  
[RootPubIndex] [D66035CB-B7AD-4D54-9FC7-AE6E7F32662D]  
[DadPubIndex] [D66035CB-B7AD-4D54-9FC7-AE6E7F32662D]
[class] [company]
```

[image: CSBaumkontakt before change]

**After** the change it looks like this:

contact person

```
[RelPubIndex] [9FC6CD387AE91B46A471E1B82963E36A]
[RooPubIndex] [D66035CB-B7AD-4D54-9FC7-AE6E7F32662D]
[DadPubIndex] [2143640C-3ABF-440C-B094-2128F4495874]
[class] [contact person]
```

company of the contact person

```
[RelPubIndex] [2143640C-3ABF-440C-B094-2128F4495874]  
[RootPubIndex] [D66035CB-B7AD-4D54-9FC7-AE6E7F32662D]  
[DadPubIndex] [D66035CB-B7AD-4D54-9FC7-AE6E7F32662D]
[class] [company]
```

[image]

Now I need an `UPDATE` script which sets the `RooPubIndex` of every contact person to the `DadPubindex`/`RootPubIndex` (if the same, but it should usually be so) from its company.

I'm a bit at loss how to connect those rows within the same table to `UPDATE` the records with the desired values. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (And I can't read that tiny image text...)

Comment: @jarlh: I've added formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've made a solution. Still need to review the data, but it seems like it works.

```
update csbaum1 set csbaum1.rootpubindex = csbaum2.DadPubIndex  
from CSBaumKontakt as csbaum1  
inner join CSBaumKontakt as csbaum2 
on csbaum1.DadPubIndex = csbaum2.RelPubIndex  
where csbaum1.Klasse = 'contact person'  
and csbaum1.RootPubIndex <> csbaum2.DadPubIndex  
and csbaum2.RootPubIndex = csbaum2.dadpubindex
```

Thanks for reading.